Removing 10th smallest and 10th largest filter in package rms graphing
I am using the "rms" package to graph predicted values of a coxph model. However, my graphs do not show my entire range of values. Upon inspection, the package vignette under the "datadist" function states:
q.display: set of two quantiles for computing the range of continuous variables to use
in displaying regression relationships. Defaults are q and 1 − q, where q =
10/max(n, 200), and n is the number of non-missing observations. Thus for
n < 200, the .05 and .95 quantiles are used. For n ≥ 200, the 10th smallest and
50 datadist
10th largest values are used. If you specify q.display, those quantiles are used
whether or not n < 200.
I tried to call:
dd <- datadist(df, q.display = c(0,1));
options(datadist='dd') 

and:
dd <- datadist(df, q.effect = c(0,1), q.display = c(0,1));
options(datadist='dd')

to include all of the data. Neither of these worked. Is
Is there a way to turn off these quantile ranges and allow the predict function to create a graph using the entire set of data?

q.display=c(0,1) is used in the examples on ?datadist, so is expected to work. Please provide a reproducible example, and be specific in how the output is different from what you expect.

q.display=c(0,1) did work upon refreshing everything!
